# MBP system reports 2 disks while About this Mac->Storage shows one HD?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

MacBook Pro mid 2010 system reports 2 disks (320G and SSD) while About this Mac-> Storage only shows one disk. This Mac -> Storage shows only one disk: 320G. I have tried to use diskutil list, it shows two disks as well.

Wonder what causes the different disk configurations?  MBP runs normally. Should I care about the difference?

Furthermore occasionally the Storage shows two disks, (not sure when), including 320G and the SSD, then the MacBook Pro crashed very often, say, every 15 minutes. 
[image: 320G]
[image: SSD]
[image: diskutil list]
Please help and thanks a million.

Comment: Please post the output of `diskutil list` to your question.  Also, at one point, you say your MBP “runs normally” then you say it “crashes every 15 mins”. Please clarify as to which one of the conditions exist.

Comment: the third image shows output of diskutil list. Sorry for the confusion, my question has two parts, the first part is on why disk info are displayed differently; the second part is somewhat related to the first question that my MBP may become unstable/crash when this machine->storage shows two disks. This happened a few times, not quite sure when and why it would happen. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You clearly have two separate devices: one a 5400rpm rotational hard drive, and the other an 'after-market' Intel SSD of 160 Gb.

There's limited space in an MBP, so is it possible that your optical (DVD) drive has been replaced with a housing for an SSD?

If you set Finder preferences to show hard disks on the Desktop, does the SSD show up?

Crashes could be caused by a defective SATA connector, either to the SSD or to your hard drive. These parts are known to fail: you can buy replacements very cheaply. If the connector to the SSD is failing, that might also explain why it's missing.

With a 10-year-old mechanical drive and a possibly failing connector to a third-party SSD installed in the optical drive bay, you might want to open it up, replace the hard drive with a new, large-capacity SSD, and investigate any physical problems with the existing SSD and housing.

Comment: Have set Finder preferences to show hard disks on the Desktop, no show of SSD. Maybe I can remove the SSD first, see what will happen, at least make my MBP stable, no more crash. Thanks